# unable to pass model to another partial view in a view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, partial-views, viewbag, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

My View Page with a partial view is:

```
@model App.Models.UpcomingPassedEventViewModel

<section class="container clearfix">
@Html.Partial("_CommentBox")
```

and my partial view _CommentBox Is having a dropdown like this:

```
@model QlutoApp.Models.Neighbourhood

@Html.DropDownList("Locations", ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId as SelectList, "Select a location")
```

As u can see above, Partial view is dependent on Models.Neighbourhood and View page is dependent on Models.UpcomingPassedEventViewModel

Now, My Controller where i am trying to send data through ViewBag is:

```
  public ActionResult MyFolder()
    {
        ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId = new SelectList(allNeighbourhood(), "Id", "NeighbourhoodName");
        int currentUserId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        var events = this.db.Events
            .Where(e => e.AuthorId == currentUserId)
            .OrderBy(e => e.StartDateTime)
            .Select(e => new EventsViewModel()
            {
                StartDateTime = e.StartDateTime,
                Title = e.Title,    
            });

        var upcomingEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now);
        var passedEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime <= DateTime.Now);
        return View(new UpcomingPassedEventViewModel()
        {
            UpcomingEvents = upcomingEvents,
            PassedEvents = passedEvents,
            allNeighbourhood = new SelectList(allNeighbourhood(), "Id", "NeighbourhoodName")
        });
    }
```

My Viewmodel is here:

```
   public class UpcomingPassedEventViewModel
    {
    public IEnumerable<EventsViewModel> UpcomingEvents { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<EventsViewModel> PassedEvents { get; set; }
    public Neighbourhood Neighbourhood { get; set; }
    public SelectList allNeighbourhood { get; set; }
    }
```

I am passing everything required by the view page through this view model but still its not working.On others view pages, there was no problem as they were not strongly binded to any model class so data is easily passing to partial view.But on this particular page, its showing error.The error is:

```
  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'App.Models.UpcomingPassedEventViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'App.Models.Neighbourhood'.
```

where i am going wrong. Please help me out.

Comment: No you said : _I am passing everything required by the view page_ but you are not passing the required **Neighbourhood** property.

Comment: The message is self explanatory. You need to use `@Html.Partial("_CommentBox", Model.Neighbourhood)` because your partial expects a model which is type of `Neighbourhood`

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'App.Models.UpcomingPassedEventViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'App.Models.Neighbourhood'. still same message after passing Model.Neighbourhood @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then thats because the vakle of your `Neighbourhood` property is `null` - you should initialize it before you pass it to the view (or you could use `@Html.Partial("_CommentBox", new Neighbourhood())`

Comment: got it working thnxx @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

You are missing instance of your Neighbourhood model in your partial view.

This will do the work.

```
@model App.Models.UpcomingPassedEventViewModel

<section class="container clearfix">
@Html.Partial("_CommentBox", Model.Neighbourhood )
```